# Cannot connect to VM in bluemix UK Area via SSH

Tags: ssh, virtual-machine, ibm-cloud

Has anybody tried out virtual machines in the UK area of bluemix?

I am able to start a vm but get an timeout when i try so connect to the vm via ssh.

I used the std Debian image that can be choosen on setup time and injected an ssh key for connecting. The security group I used was allow_all.

When trying to ping or to connect via ssh directly or the openstack cli the connection times out.

regards
Johannes

Comment: Have you seen the information on "Adding the rule to allow pinging VM instances by using the OSC client" in the docs? I wanted to reference it in case the info helps. See: https://www.ng.bluemix.net/docs/virtualmachines/vm_index.html

Comment: Did you execute the ssh sending your private key? ssh -vv -i your.key ibmcloud@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was a bug in the setup of the vm, so I actually had no chance to access it.